# .htaccess not rewriting the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this problem:
The administrator of the server says that he had rewrite_module enabled for the apache server but when I upload some test files to the server to test this functionality it does not work.

I have it enabled at localhost and it works perfectly fine there.

.htaccess content:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ games.php?id=$1 [L]
```

games.php content:

```
<?php 
$var = $_GET['id'];
echo $var;
?>
```

URLS:

```
localhost url:http://localhost/testing/games/123123
production url:http://mysite.com/test2/games/123123
```

test2 is the folder that contains the files (.htaccess and games.php)
What happens in production is that when i type this i get the page games.php but the id does not get echoed and query string is empty instead of getting the id 123123 which I provided.For localhost everything works fine and I get the id echoed.
Maybe the administrator is wrong or what? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are in subdirectories and you're telling the engine to rewrite when the request begins exactly with 'games'. You can try to remove the caret ^, or replace it with a slash / ... or add this after RewriteEngine on :

```
RewriteBase /testing/
```

in production:

```
RewriteBase /test2/
```

Or try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ games.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Also, you may want to double-check if AllowOverride is set to All in the apache config file so that the .htaccess is allowed to override settings such as mod_rewrite.

Comment: It's not working. I think that the htaccess does not get called at all. Because when i delete it and type: mysite.com/test2/games the file games.php gets called instead of throwing error 404. When I type mysite.com/test2/games/213123 I get the same result- games.php gets called again :(

Comment: is there any .htaccess in a parent directory? if so, try to remove it

Comment: Not working again, I even moved it to the root folder same result. I tried this on other server and it worked so i guess it's the server...